# Edit class list of element in Razor Page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a Razor Page and in the HTML there's a list of buttons and I want to be able to change the class list on those buttons to highlight the currently selected one. Each button looks like so:

```
<form asp-page-handler="Posts" method="post">
    <button href="posts" class="nav-link text-white active" aria-current="page">
        Posts
    </button>
</form>
```

When it is clicked it will call a handler method and I want to add the active class to it and remove the active class from the previous one. This would be trivial in javascript and maybe it is in c# but after an hour of searching, I can't find a way to do this.

Comment: You mean something like `class="....@(isactive ? "active" : null)"?

Comment: If you want  to do it without js,you may need to have a list to save the id of the buttons,active or not of the buttons,content of the buttons.When call the handler,you need to pass the id of the selected button,and the data of the list to handler,change the selected button active in handler.

Comment: I wonder if you have any special needs that can't use js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working demo to add the active class to selected button without js:
cshtml.cs:

```
[BindProperty]
        public List<Button> buttons { get; set; }
 public void OnGet()
        {
            buttons = new List<Button> { new Button { Id = 1, Content = "button1" }, new Button { Id = 2, Content = "button2"}, new Button { Id = 3, Content = "button3" } };
public IActionResult OnPostPosts(int id)
        {
            buttons.ForEach(b => b.IsActive = false);
            buttons.Where(b => b.Id == id).ToList().ForEach(b => b.IsActive = true);
            //save data to database,add data to gridBind

            return Page();
        }
            
           
        }
```

Button.cs:

```
 public class Button {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }


    }
```

View:

```
<form method="post">
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.buttons.Count; i++)
    {
        <input hidden name="buttons[@i].Id" value=@Model.buttons[i].Id />
        <input hidden name="buttons[@i].Content" value=@Model.buttons[i].Content />
        <input hidden name="buttons[@i].IsActive" value=@Model.buttons[i].IsActive />


    }
    @foreach (var item in Model.buttons)
    {
        <input  type="submit" asp-page-handler="Posts" asp-route-id="@item.Id" class="nav-link text-white @(item.IsActive ? "active" : "")" aria-current="page" value="@item.Content" />

    }

</form>
```

result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution below uses jquery/js.

1. Add data-attribute to all the `.nav-link` buttons. I used data-page.

```
<button data-page="posts href="posts" class="nav-link text-white" aria-current="page">
   Posts
</button>
```

2. In your Posts page get handler, assign "posts" to a certain viewdata index.

```
ViewData["ActivePage"] = "posts";
```

3. Then in the layout.cshtml, add this script.

```
@section scripts {
   <script> 
      $(document).ready(function(){
         @if(ViewData["ActivePage"] != null)
         {
            <text>var activePage = "@ViewData["ActivePage"]";</text>
         }
         else
         {
            <text>var activePage = "";</text>
         }

         // loop through navlinks and assign/remove active class
         $(".nav-link").each(function(){
            var dataPage = $(this).data("page");

            if(dataPage == activePage){
               $(this).addClass("active");
            }
            else{
               $(this).removeClass("active");
            }
         });
      });
   </script>
}
```

For the other buttons, you just need to assign unique data-page; `data-page= "other name";`

Then in their respective handler methods, add `ViewData["ActivePage"] = "other name";`

Since the script will be included in layout, it would activate for all the pages.

Answer (score 0):

I use jquery/js write a simple demo here to show when click on the button, button will add `active` class and `Bold borders` to show the difference and remove the active class from the previous one

```
<form asp-page-handler="Index" method="post">
    <button href="posts" class="nav-link text-black " aria-current="page" id="btn_submit1">
        Posts
    </button>
</form>
<br />
<form asp-page-handler="Index" method="post">
    <button href="posts" class="nav-link text-black " aria-current="page" id="btn_submit2">
        Posts1
    </button>
</form>
<br />
<form asp-page-handler="Index" method="post">
    <button href="posts" class="nav-link text-black " aria-current="page" id="btn_submit3">
        Posts2
    </button>
</form>

//...............

@section Scripts{
    <head>      
    <style>           
          .active{
                border: solid;
            }
    </style>
</head>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            var data = localStorage.getItem("index");
            if(data!=null){
                $("#"+data).addClass('active');
            }
        })

        $("button").click(function () {     
        localStorage.setItem("index",  this.id );
    });
    </script>
}
```

[image]